# Determine a set of numbers configured a certain way?

Tags: analysis

I need to determine a set of numbers in this configuration:

123
456
789

The sum of 3 numbers cannot equal the sum of 3 numbers either left, right, up, down, or diagonally.

e.g.

4+5+6 == 7+5+3 == 15 *is* acceptable
7+2+9 == 3+6+9 == 18 *is not* acceptable

How can I determine what set of numbers will meet this criteria?

Comment: What i sthe significance of 7+2+9?

Comment: Hard to guess what you want. Do you want to create a magic $3\times 3$-square ?

Comment: **Hagen** - 7+2+9 is just an example using the numbers I gave (1-9). They are not significant other than showing this configuration is disqualifying.

**Peter** - I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A magic $3\times 3$-square is

$$\pmatrix{6&1&8\\7&5&3\\2&9&4}$$

Upto symmetries, this is overmore the only possibility.